# What is the reasonf for "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'engine'" and how to fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

This error occurred when I try to run my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\loveislife\Desktop\PyProject\J.A.R.V.I.S - Copy\script.py", line 83, in <module>
import pyttsx
File "C:\Users\loveislife\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\pyttsx\__init__.py", 
line 18, in <module>
from engine import Engine
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'engine'.
```

And this error occurred when I open cmd prompt to import engine:

```
C:\Users\loveislife>pip install engine
Collecting engine
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement engine (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for engine
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

From google, try installing and importing pyttsx3, which is the updated version for python 3, and it should work.

Comment: It says "It is the Latest Version of pyttsx3 on Pypi".